# JS: Flying random objects (images)

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, google-ads-api

I have small question about my concept in photoshop:

[image]

I need to create html5/css/js adwords banner, where they will levitate background images (red pentagons) but also at the forefront of the entire banner, because in addition to those levitating pictures there will be other objects (texts, buttons).

It is possible to achive this, and also it is possible change path of moving these red pentagons base base on cursor position if user will move his cursor on over that banner?

Edit:
I found this project: https://codepen.io/VIRU/pen/FAdkl
Can be edited for flying pictures?

```
window.onload = function() {

    //Create canvas and initialize it's context
    var canvas = document.getElementById("flying-bubbles");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Set the dimensions of canvas equal to the window's dimensions
    var W = window.innerWidth, H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;

    //Create an array of circles
    var circles = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
        circles.push(new create_circle());
    }

    //Function to create circles with different positions and velocities
    function create_circle() {
        //Random Position
        this.x = Math.random()*W;
        this.y = Math.random()*H;

        //Random Velocities
        this.vx = 0.1+Math.random()*1;
        this.vy = -this.vx;

        //Random Radius
        this.r = 10 + Math.random()*50;
    }

    //Function to draw the background
    function draw() {
        //Create the gradient
        var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, W, H);
        grad.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(19, 105, 168)');
        grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');

        //Fill the canvas with the gradient
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,W,H);

        //Fill the canvas with the circles
        for(var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
            var c = circles[j];

            //Draw the circle and it with the blur grad
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";       
            ctx.fillStyle = grad;
            ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.fill();

            //Lets use the velocity now
            c.x += c.vx;
            c.y += c.vy;

            //To prevent the circles from moving out of the canvas
            if(c.x < -50) c.x = W+50;
            if(c.y < -50) c.y = H+50;
            if(c.x > W+50) c.x = -50;
            if(c.y > H+50) c.y = -50;
        }
    }

    setInterval(draw, 25);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? These are canvas HTML elements, you can use images if you like, and link them however you like in Javascript.. Also what about Adwords ? Are you sure you don't mean adsense ? In which case IIRC modifying the advert is against the TOS from Google..

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/zimon/pen/KNmKpN

Try to change circles drawing to the image.

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src= 'http://www.media3.net/images/redsquare.png';

    ctx.drawImage(img,c.x,c.y);
```

Comment: Nice, and its possible add random generate size of that image, but with ofcourse some limits to prevent some oversize images? and also random blur effects apply on that images? :)

Comment: Edoras, asking for 3 additional features, when showing no proof of effort on your part is a little bit bold no ?